# Swift string tokenization

Tags: ios, swift

Why can I do this

```
let dataArray = data.characters.split{$0 == ";"}.map(String.init)
```

and this

```
let dataArray = self.dataIn.characters.split{$0 == "\r\n"}.map(String.init)
```

but I can't do this?

```
let dataArray = data.characters.split{$0 == "; "}.map(String.init)
```

I want to look for the string

```
"; "
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you are splitting on characters here so your "`$0`" is a `Character` type. Meaning it can never be equal to a non-character object. `"; "` is a string, since it is not a single character.

That being said, if you are only attempting to split the string by `"; "`, you should just use the String's `components(separatedBy:)`:

```
let dataArray = data.components(separatedBy: "; ")
```

Comment: excellent. Thank you. When I originally googled this and even now I get the characters.split solution at the top of my search. It seems to work with the "\r\n" so I'm a little confused.

Comment: `\r\n` is actually only matching new line characters, so it is still a single `Character`. For example `\n\n` won't work since that is two "characters".